# Deadlock on same table when creating partition in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, partitioning, deadlock

PostgreSQL 14.1. I have a partitioned table liked this:

```
create table dataset_session
(
    dataset_id integer not null references dataset (id)
    session_id integer not null,
    external_id uuid not null references session (external_id)
) partition by list (dataset_id);
```

When multiple clients simultaneously try to create a partition of it this often fails with a deadlock, like this:

```
    Detail: Process 21929 waits for AccessExclusiveLock on relation 173796 (dataset_session) of database 173691; blocked by process 26983.
Process 26983 waits for AccessExclusiveLock on relation 173796 (dataset_session) of database 173691; blocked by process 21929.

    Where: SQL statement "create table dataset_session_50 partition of dataset_session (
            constraint dataset_session_50_pkey primary key (session_id),
            constraint dataset_session_50_external_id_uq unique (external_id)
        ) for values in (50);
```

Note that both processes apparently have an exclusive lock on the same table (dataset_session, the parent table) - how is this possible? And how do I fix this?

My understanding was always that you need multiple statements in a transaction to cause a deadlock, but I'm only running that one statement in the transaction! (It's done by a procedure which calls "commit;" before and after.)

**Edit:** Interestingly, the deadlock does not happen with 2 other partitioned tables that seem very similar to this one.

Comment: Surprising. It would be great if you could capture `pg_locks` before the deadlock detector hits, but I know that is difficult.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Thanks for the hint. I captured `pg_locks` (not sure if at the right moment or not!) but it didn't really tell me anything. I managed to figure out a workaround anyway, though not the cause (see answer).

Answer (score 0):

While I never figured out the cause of this, I figured out the workaround: create the two constraints on the partition separately from the partition itself:

```
    execute format('create table dataset_session_%1$s partition of dataset_session
        /*(
            constraint dataset_session_%1$s_pkey primary key (session_id), -- deadlocks!
            constraint dataset_session_%1$s_external_id_uq unique (external_id) -- deadlocks!
        )*/
        for values in (%1$s);

        alter table dataset_session_%1$s add constraint dataset_session_%1$s_pkey primary key (session_id); -- does not deadlock!
        alter table dataset_session_%1$s add constraint dataset_session_%1$s_external_id_uq unique (external_id);  -- does not deadlock!',
            dataset_internal_id);
```

Note that these still all run in the same `execute` statement and therefore in the same transaction, so I wouldn't have thought it would make a difference, but it does.

Answer (score 0):

I've been having a similar issue the past couple days. In my case, adding a partition conflicts with inserting data into a partition via constraints, or selecting data from multiple partitions. I have been able to solve it by acquiring an explicit table lock on the base table before attempting to add a partition. Note that I initially tried an EXCLUSIVE lock, and still got occasional deadlocks. Here is the lock that works:

`LOCK TABLE "<base_table>" IN ACCESS EXCLUSIVE MODE;`

This acquires a lock on the base table, and all existing partition tables. It seems pretty intrusive, but it's done in a function that, in production, is only called about once per day. There is no need for explicit locking in "regular" queries that select/insert from/into.